# Legend based on geom rather than aesthetic with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

The idea here is to draw a legend for each `geom` with the same aesthetic. In the example below the legend generated assumes that these two different layers are in the same scale, resulting in this map.

I want, as a result, that the legend in the graph is separated in two, so I can change these with a `scale_fill_*` for each layer.

I'm aware of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24874007/11056037, but I'm looking for a more elegant and scalable way to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geobr)

mun <- map(11:12, read_municipality) %>%
    map(mutate, index = seq_along(code_muni), .before = geom)

mun[[2]] <- mun[[2]] %>%
    mutate(index = index + 100)

mun <- mun %>%
    map(
        ~mutate(.x, index = cut(index, quantile(index), include.lowest = TRUE))
    )

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = mun[[1]], aes(fill = index)) +
    geom_sf(data = mun[[2]], aes(fill = index))
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: More than only semantics, and to clarify the grammar of graphics (the gg bit in ggplot) - legends will always map to an aesthetic, i.e., to the "look" of your geom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Legends for multiple fills in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185291/legends-for-multiple-fills-in-ggplot)

Comment: No, but stefan's answer solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and guides for the same aesthetic:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geobr)
library(ggnewscale)

pal1 <- scales::hue_pal()(8)[1:4]
pal2 <- scales::hue_pal()(8)[5:8]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mun[[1]], aes(fill = index)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal1) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_sf(data = mun[[2]], aes(fill = index)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal2)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly this! Thank you!